# How to set current path to executing batch file location?

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have created a windows scheduler task to execute a batch file in c:\codes directory, in the batch file i have written commands to execute few jar files which are in location where the executing batch file is present,but while that task is executing it is showing an error:

`C:\Windows\system32>SET mypath=C:\codes\
C:\Windows\system32>java -jar CreateAttachments.jar
Error: Unable to access jarfile CreateAttachments.jar`

content in batch file is:

`SET mypath=%~dp0
java -jar CreateAttachments.jar
java -jar SendEmailsInSheduledTime.jar
echo 'Task completed'
exit`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use either `pushd "%~dp0"` or `cd /D "%~dp0"`

Open a command prompt window and enter `pushd /?` and later `cd /?` for details on those 2 commands to change working directory.

Comment: Oh, cool. Thank you so much its working, and i have one more requirement ie., i want to hide this command prompt while the jar files are executing, will you please suggest me the solution for this